# How to align ngx-bootstrap date picker to top left or bottom left

Tags: html, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I want to customize ngx-bootstrap datepicker to either align to bottom left or top left based on the input position.The input is on the right end of the screen therefore i have given the position as `left`. But since the input can be present in the bottom or top corner of the parent div which leads to either the upper or bottom part getting cropped due to `left` positon. Even `position="bottom left"` or `position="top left"` doesn't seem to work now.

This is what i have tried :

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="maxvalue" type="text" class="form-control" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMMM-YYYY', showWeekNumbers:false, customStopEventPropagation:true}" placement="left" />
```

How do i achieve this behaviour?